# What is the highest possible prediction accuracy when I flip some labels at random?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, accuracy, mlp, mnist

I want to predict MNIST labels in a binary setting using a simple MLP model (0 for digits 0-4 and 1 for 5-9). For the train and test data, I randomly flip 25% of the labels.

Is the maximum achievable prediction accuracy 75% in this setting or is it even higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum achievable prediction accuracy in this setting would be 75%. Since 25% of the labels are flipped randomly, the model would not be able to correctly predict those flipped labels. However, it can still predict the remaining 75% of the labels accurately.